# Logging every step and action by Python in a Large Script

Tags: python, trace

I have created a large python script at the end. But now I need a logger for it. I have input steps, prompts.. Function calls.. While Loops.., etc. in the script.

And also, the logger is have to log success operations too.

I couldn't find a suitable answer for me. I'm searching on the internet again, and wanted to ask you too.

Whats your opinion?

Thanks

Comment: so you mean saving a trace of the operating code or just a logging library?

Comment: Actually yes, I want to save (actually mail) trace of the operation but not the print part (output), background part too.. (Like if I execute os.system ('sleep 5') it will log like system is going to sleep 5 seconds. or whatever the system default thinking is.)

Comment: You'd better search on internet and ask us if you don't find an answer... SO is for unanswered questions...

Comment: I would think that this is a good start: http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html

Comment: I have already searched @gecco, asked to SO and now re-searching (again). I couldn't find a suitable answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's a module [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) in the standard library. Basic usage is very simple; in every module that needs to do logging, put

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and log with, e.g.,

```
logger.info("Doing something interesting")
logger.warn("Oops, something's not right")
```

Then in the main module, put something like

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

to print all logs with a severity of `INFO` or worse to standard error. The module is very configurable, see [its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) for details.

Comment: I didn't had chance to implement it. Sorry for delay.